# Recently installed ubuntu 14.04 but continues to restart laptop

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, live-cd

I've been trying to run ubuntu 14.04 off a usb on my Win 8.1 laptop. I get the dual boot OS selection screen on startup but each time I select ubuntu, the system restarts. I got the same result trying to run it off a live CD. What did I failed to do?

Comment: Remove and Live CD/DVD or USB Flash drives from your disk then try booting again.

Comment: Have you trying booting directly from the USB rather than from the Windows8.1 MBR?

Comment: Perhaps UEFI...

Answer (score 0):

Try to download again and check for errors , then use unetbootin for usb . Then try to boot using the quick boot menu when the computer starts .